# How can I monitor IoT devices in real-time while on a plane?

Tags: communication

As a frequent traveler (for work and research), currently, a lot of this travel is by plane. While in flight, I have to have my devices (that are with me obviously) in flight mode. This is a standard regulation for flights, so this question may be a bit of a stretch.

My situation is similar to what AstroDan mentions in his comment [here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/186/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-large-numbers-of-iot-devices-remotely#comment318_186) on his question "[Is there a way to turn on large numbers of IoT devices remotely?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/186/254)", where I am monitoring a set of small solar power monitors (that I inherited from a retiring professor).

Asides from recording the data, these small devices need to be monitored to make sure they don't overheat (if the cooling systems fail), which at the very least causes a distortion in the monitoring results and at worst, cause the device to burnout.

Is there a way to be able to monitor (real-time) the devices while on a plane?

Comment: Depends on the airline I suppose. Do you have access to any devices which can transmit data between the plane and the ground? If not, you're looking at smoke signals or semaphore. Not easy on planes.

Comment: What could you do if they do start overheating, while being on a plane? Could that action be automated, so you don't have to be personally involved?

Answer (score 10):

Some airlines provide in-flight wireless connectivity, usually for a fee. You can use WiFi in "Airplane Mode" on most mobile devices, so that would let you connect to a monitoring server to retrieve the status of your devices, but you would still be unable to monitor your devices during taxi/takeoff/landing periods when your devices (even the small handheld ones) must be powered down.